# I can't store the data into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, insert

So I have this form. I would like to store the data into my database. However, it's not and there is no error log. I would really appreciate help, as it's due in 2 days and I've been trying for the past week or so.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="preview.php" method="post" class="f">
                <p>

                <p>
                            <p><label for="name">Teacher's Name:</label>
                                <input type="text" style="font-family:Gloria Hallelujah" size="35" name="name" id="name" autofocus required></p>
                            <p><label for="name">Title:</label>
                                <input type="text" style="font-family:Gloria Hallelujah" size="35" name="title" id="title" autofocus required></p>  
                            <p><label for="done">Done By:</label>
                                <input type="text" style="font-family:Gloria Hallelujah" size="35" name="done" id="done" required></p>
                            <p><label for="no">Class:</label>
                                <input type="text" style="font-family:Gloria Hallelujah" size="15" name="class" id="no" required></p>
                            <p><label for="sch">School:</label>
                                <select name="sch">
                                    <option value="seg">School of Engineering (SEG)</option>
                                    <option value="sit">School of Information Technology (SIT)</option>
                                    <option value="sdn">School of Design (SDN)</option>
                                    <option value="sbm">School of Business Management (SBM)</option>
                                    <option value="shs">School of Health Sciences (SHS)</option>
                                    <option value="scl">School of Chemical & Life Sciences (SCL)</option>
                                    <option value="sidm">School of Interactive and Digital Media (SIDM)</option>
                                </select>

                                            <p><label for="msg">Show your Gratitude! :</label>
                            <textarea class="tarea" maxlength="3000" cols="38.5" rows="6" name="comments" placeholder="Enter Message here..." required></textarea>
                            <p class="limit">Char limit: 3000 chars.</p>
                        </p>
```

And it goes to preview.php where it is supposed to store the data.

```
<?php
include "mysqli.connect.php";
include "fbmain.php";

$sql = "INSERT INTO table(teacherName, title, doneBy, studentClass, school, message)VALUES    ('$_POST[name]','$_POST[title]','$_POST[done]','$_POST[class]','$_POST[comments]') where     facebookId = '".$me['id']."'";
```

Comment: remove where condition from insert query

Comment: e.g. '{$_POST['name']}' but see about sql injection and prepared statements - oh, and that too

Comment: Be very careful when using $_POST[name] directly in the sql due to SQL injections http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work

Comment: Tried the  '{$_POST['name']}', but doesn't work. I'm not so worried about the SQL injections.

Answer (score 0):

`INSERT` command does not need `WHERE` clause .

**P.S :** You are wide open to [**SQL Injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: Dear Alireza this is Error Reporter for Mysqli `if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo mysqli_connect_error();
  exit();
}`

Comment: @Exclusified try `echo mysqli_connect_error(); exit();`

Answer (score 0):

```
('$_POST[name]','$_POST[title]','...
```

Change to:

```
('{$_POST[name]}','{$_POST[title]}','...
```

this is better

see https://www.php.net/mysqli_query
And check Database And check `WHERE` structs 
You can Display Errors And Fix them By Put  this code After Query

```
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo mysqli_connect_error();
  exit();
}
```

Comment: Changed it, but it didn't work. I tried to display the error also, but there was no error.

Comment: "Alireza said:" ` where     facebookId = '".$me['id']."'` Is invalid Struct For INSERT!!!

Comment: It's Bad Problem And i haven't this Source ... maybe Error is for other code's .And i haven't' enough Time ;)

Answer (score 0):

$_POST[name] isn't the same as $_POST['name'], $_POST[title] isn't the same as $_POST['title'] etc.

Instead of:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table(teacherName, title, doneBy, studentClass, school, message)VALUES    ('$_POST[name]','$_POST[title]','$_POST[done]','$_POST[class]','$_POST[comments]') where     facebookId = '".$me['id']."'";
```

try

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$title = $_POST['title'];
$done = $_POST['done'];
$class = $_POST['class'];
$comments = $_POST['comments'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO table(teacherName, title, doneBy, studentClass, school, message)VALUES    ('{$name}','{$title}','{$done}','{$class}','{comments}') where     facebookId = '".$me['id']."'";
```

But above is just to get it to work!

It isn't the recommended way of doing this. You should do it with parametized queries... http://forum.codecall.net/topic/44392-php-5-mysqli-prepared-statements/

Comment: What are the values given into the variables + value of $me['id'] ?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm very new to PHP. I don't quite understand your question.

Comment: If you do echo $name; - what does it print to the screen?